# weird context is not accessed pylance problem (win 10)

Tags: python, bots, artificial-intelligence, telegram

i tried to create a telegram bot using a video i saw on youtube and wrote the following code:

```
from typing import final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, filters, MessageHandler, ContextTypes
TOKEN : final = "Token goes here"
BOT_USERNAME : final = "my bot ID goes here"

#commands
async def start_command(Update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    #await context()
    await Update.message.reply_text ("hi")

async def help_command(Update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    #await context()
    await Update.message.reply_text ("this is help!")


#handling the responses

def handle_response(text: str)-> str: 
    if "hello!" in text: 
        return "hi!"
    
async def handle_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_type: str = update.message.chat.type
    text: str = update.message.text

    print(f'user ({update.message.chat.id}) in {message_type}: "{text}"')

    if message_type == "group": 
        if BOT_USERNAME in text:
            new_text: str = text.replace(BOT_USERNAME, "").strip()
            response: str = handle_response(new_text)
        else:
            return
    else:
        response: str = handle_response(text)
    
    print("bot", response)
    await update.message.reply_text(response)
    
async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE): 
    print(f"update {update} caused error {context.error}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting bot...")
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    #COMMAND HANDLING HERE!!!!
    
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start" ,start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("help" ,help_command))

    #MESSAGES

    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Text, handle_message))

    #ERROR

    app.add_error_handler(error)

    #REFRESH

    print("refreshing...")
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=2)
```

the problem is that in #commands section the context is greyed out and vs code says it's not accessed pylance.
now when i copy and paste the same code in another pc it works fine and this does not happen. What might be the problem?

i tried importing CAllBAckContext instead of Conetct_Types but it didn't work.
it works totally fine in another os (linux) but not in my own.
python-telegram-bot is already installed